# Rodar array com metódo WHEN, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pois bem, eu possuo uma array de números e preciso enviar cada um separadamanete ao servidor, porém eu preciso esperar que todos sejam executados antes de executar minha ação final. Pesquisei e então descobri o metódo/função `WHEN` que espera as requisições todas serem fechadas para executar X função.

O problema é que eu não sei como rodar todo o conteúdo da array e inseri-la nesse WHEN.. Não tenho mínima idéia..

Veja um exemplo demonstrativo dela:

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
```

mas meus dados da array não tem só `a1, a2, a3 e a4` eles podem ter muito mais até "infinitos" ou simplesmente 1 ou dois ítens.

Minha array no caso: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,77,44,23423,234212344]`

Ah, eu uso `forEach` para rodar a array

Comment: Segundo o exemplo `$.when(p1, p2).done(retorno1, retorno2){ alert(retorno1 + ' : ' + retorno2) }` temos 2 requisições que são `p1` e `p2`, onde os seus retornos são `retorno1` e `retorno2`, mas ainda assim a tua dúvida não está clara, e não sei ao certo, o que responder.

Comment: E tens esses ida da array todos de uma vez numa array ou vais recebendo ids um a um? Se explicares melhor como a aplicação funciona fica mais claro

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que enviar "1 a infinitos" pedidos ajax simultaneamente não é muito boa ideia.

De facto o jQUery tem uma nova API para promises e podes passar vários pedidos ajax como argumentos de `$.when()` e depois correr uma função quando todas tiverem sido corridas usando o `.done()`.

Se fôr o caso de teres um numero razoável numeros nessa array acho boa ideia usar o `$.when()`, senão acho que devias usar também o `.then()`, para os pedidos esperarem uns pelos outros.

Para responder à tua pergunta podes fazer assim:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,77,44,23423,234212344];
var ajaxArray= array.map(function(nr){
    return $.ajax({url: 'meusite.com', data: nr});
});
$.when.apply($, array).done(function(){
    alert('está pronto!');
    console.log(arguments); // array onde cada elemento corresponde à resposta de cada pedido ajax
});
```

Se quiseres encadiar em vez de enviar todos de uma vez podes usar assim:

```
var pr = $.Deferred(); // promise vazia
array.forEach(function(el){
    pr = pr.then(function(){
        return $.ajax({url: 'meusite.com', data: nr});
    });
});

pr.then(function(){
    // esta é a ultima chamada e onde podes correr o codigo final
});
```

Comment: Oi, eu disse infinitos apenas para tentar deixar mais clara a pergunta, mas o máximo seria de 100 itens na array, seria muito? Tens alternativa melhor?

Comment: @Elaine os pedidos precisam de esperar uns pelos outros? não dá para enviar todos os dados num só pedido?

Comment: Precisam sim.. Infelizmente, veja, cada número corresponde a um ID que buscará a sua respectiva chave pública no servidor para encriptar um conteúdo.. e só depois que cada um tiver seu conteúdo encriptado que poderei fechar com  a função final. Mas se bem que eu poderia resgatar todas as chaves de uma só vez.. tem idéias?